# Transfering TFS to Git with history till certain date

Tags: git, github, tfs, git-tfs, git-tf

I am in the process of transferring our code from TFS to git as per the article [here](http://chriskirby.net/migrate-an-existing-project-from-tfs-to-github-with-changeset-history-intact/)

The tool use the following command to clone TFS version to local repository along with all the history.

```
git-tf clone https://myaccount.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection $/MyBigProject/MyMainBranch --deep
```

I want to know instead cloning all the history is there any way to clone history till certain date

**EDIT1**
Both tools (git-tfs and git-tf) fetch source code + history at TFS branch or folder level. I want to fetch only certain folders from the TFS branch. For example this is how my TFS branch looks like:

MyTFSTeamProject -> MyTFSBranch ->
   ProjectFolder1
   ProjectFolder2
   ProjectFolder3
   ProjectFolder4
   LibraryFolder

I want to fetch ProjectFolder1,ProjectFoler2 and Library along with it's history into local git repository and then push it GitHub

Can someone help me with the steps i need to take.

Answer (score 2):

No. But with git-tfs, you can using the option `-c=changesetId`. [here](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/clone.md#clone-from-a-specific-changeset)

Comment: thanks, i didnt know there is git-tfs also exists. Can someone please give me what would me my commands in order to move TFS branch to GitHub repository. I guess i will have to use "clone" command to download code in local repository on my machine, but whats after that commit, push ? i'm still learning how git works. We are not planning to use TFS again once the branch is moved to git.

Comment: This project was there long before and will be long after but don't have the exposition Microsoft have... I wrote a lot of documentation : https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/README.md Especially, https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md